# Column of data not appearing after web scrape (rvest and xlsx)

Tags: web-scraping, xlsx, rvest

I am currently trying to download public Treasury data and when setting up my scraping, I am only pulling the date column, 20-year column, and extrapolation factor. The 10-year column, situated in the middle of the table, is not included in the scrape and paste into excel. My code is below. directory not included.

```
url <- "https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest- 
        rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=longtermrateYear&year=2020"
ten_year_comp <- read_html(url, encoding = "table") 
ten_year_comp %>%
   html_nodes("table") %>%
   .[[4]] %>%
   html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%

write.xlsx(ten_year_comp, file = "TREASURY10YR.xlsx", sheetName = "ten_year_comp", 
           col.names = TRUE, row.names = TRUE, asTable = TRUE, append = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url <- "https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=longtermrateYear&year=2020"

ten_year_comp <- html_nodes(read_html(url), "table")[[4]] %>% html_table(fill = T)

write.xlsx(
  ten_year_comp,
  file = "TREASURY10YR.xlsx",
  sheetName = "ten_year_comp",
  col.names = TRUE,
  row.names = TRUE,
  asTable = TRUE,
  append = FALSE
)
```